# Element in Protractor where the ID is a variable

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm writing some E2E tests using Protractor. There's one text box I'm having real difficulty in getting to...using strict xpath `.//*[@id='_euj7snvsk']` wont work because the text within ' ' changes each run-time.

Here's the surrounding entry:

```html
<div class="kf-input" _ngcontent-c17="">
<!---->
<input id="_9b5w9rlmb" class="input kf-input-valid ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" _ngcontent-c17="" tabindex="0" placeholder="e.g. My living room project" required="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9']{3,40}$" type="text"/>
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
</div>
```

Tried 'getting' at the placeholder and class but with zero success. Please can anyone suggest a way forward?
Thanks
David

Comment: what is the pattern here by which the value of ID changes?Please post at    least 3 different changed ID here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//assign the variable id name in a string and use it in the locator
var idString = '_9b5w9rlmb';
var inputElement = element(by.id(idString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the element via CSS selectors? [Check out all possibilities here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Here my suggestion for your case:

```
element(by.css('div.kf-input div.input.kf-input-valid')).sendKeys('Some Text');
```

or shorter:

```
$('div.kf-input div.input.kf-input-valid').sendKeys('Some Text');
```

Note, that the `sendKeys()` is the assumption that you want to enter text. It's not clear from your question, what you want to do with the field.

Also the second class `.kf-input-valid` to identify your text box might not be necessary and/or might be changed from your code. So, if you don't need that 2nd class to uniquely identify your textbox, go without it.

In general I recommend to use CSS-Locators instead of XPath. XPath is less performing and harder to maintain on the long run.

Comment: Thank you Ernst - Yes, you're quite right - I do indeed need to send some text.

Comment: @David Redmayne. Glad I anticipated correctly. Did my suggestion work with using CSS Selectors?

Comment: @DavidRedmayne If the answer worked for you, be so kind to mark it as correct. If it didn't work, let me know how I can improve it.